# Deriving the Boltzmann distribution with Gaussian energies

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, simplex

Suppose I have a $D$ dimensional Gaussian random variable, given by

$$Y\sim N(\mu, \Sigma).$$

I would like to study the distribution of

$$X=\Big(\frac{e^{Y_1}}{\sum_ie^{Y_i}},\ldots,\frac{e^{Y_D}}{\sum_ie^{Y_i}}\Big).$$

Specifically, I would like to determine the joint pdf $p(x_1,\ldots,x_D)$, defined over the $D-1$ simplex $\Delta^{D-1}$.

I'm aware of the constructions given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit-normal_distribution#Multivariate_generalization), however neither one quite seems to fit with what I'm looking for.

The former construction essentially sets $Y_D=1$, while the latter is actually the density for

$$X=\Big(\frac{e^{Y_1}}{1+e^{Y_1}},\ldots,\frac{e^{Y_D}}{1+e^{Y_D}}\Big),$$

which is not what I want.

Comment: The latter construction is precisely what you want, with the assumption that $Y_D = 0$.

Comment: John Aitchison's book on compositional data works with this distribution.

Comment: @XiangxiangXu I'm afraid I do not follow.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, do you have a copy of that book handy?  Does it explicitly state what the pdf is?

Comment: @Thoth : I don't; I'd have to go to the library.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, ok let me know when you get there